# Construct a digraph which reflect four given rankings and use component analysis to interpret these rankings

Tags: graph-theory

> Suppose that four judges $J_1$, $J_2$, $J_3$, and $J_4$ each rank eight objects: $O_1,O_2,\ldots,O_8$ independently. Their rankings are
>
> $$\begin{array}{cc}
> J_1: & O_1\ O_2\ O_3\ O_4\ O_5\ O_6\ O_7\ O_8 \\
> J_2: & O_2\ O_4\ O_6\ O_8\ O_1\ O_3\ O_5\ O_7 \\
> J_3: & O_3\ O_5\ O_4\ O_8\ O_7\ O_6\ O_2\ O_1 \\
> J_4: & O_6\ O_7\ O_1\ O_2\ O_3\ O_4\ O_5\ O_8
> \end{array}$$
>
> Construct a digraph which reflects these rankings. Use component analysis to interpret these rankings.

This is question 7.1 (pages 120-121) from the text [Graph Theory Applications](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0933-1) by L. R. Foulds.

I tried to answer this question but I am confused about how to construct the graph. Because what I am thinking is that this digraph should be considered as a tournament and use tournament analysis to interpret rankings. But when I am drawing edges based on the judges rankings there is more than one edges between two vertices like $O_1 \rightarrow O_2$ based on $J_1$ and $O_2 \rightarrow O_1$ based on $J_3$. These cannot be present in a tournament. So I am confused how to approach this question.

Please help me to solve this question

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't understand the problem either.  I don't see "component analysis" defined in the text, and Google has not made me any more enlightened.  But here's some comments:

There's four acyclic tournaments, one for each judge, defined by the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_graph_theory) of each path:

[image: the four tournaments]

If the problem required working with tournaments, these would be them.  But this doesn't seem to be the way to approach this problem.

This is the graph you get if you take the union of the four directed paths given by the four judges:

[image: union of the four directed paths]

It's possible the author is asking for a "tournament wins analysis" (something that I've never heard of outside this book), like what they do for the tournament in Figure 7.4, except doing it for the above digraph.  This could be what the author means with "This kind of argument can be used generally."

Comment: Not having the book, and not knowing anything of the area, I feel stupid asking this - but I will anyway.  Isn't there something wrong with your final graph? The orange path between vertex 1 and 2 is 'on its own'. Also, had I been asked to rank the players from the scores above, I would have added and then sorted the scores: player 1's score is $1 + 5 + 8 + 3 = 17$ , 2's score is $ 2 + 1 + 7 + 4 = 14$, etc. Could the aim be to be read this off a graph (up to a bit of algebra), e.g., by the sum of the length of paths past a given vertex?   Sorry if I am off mark...

Comment: Oops, my drawing has overlapping edges (fixed) [I should have been more careful].  Regarding your approach to ranking them, it seems reasonable, but it's not "component analysis" as requested by the text (but undefined in the text).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones For a tournament win analysis the graph should be  a tournament. How to convert the obtained graph to a tournament?. There are edges that prevent the graph being a tournament (like 6->7 and 7->6). So how to convert the graph to a tournament?.